# Command line IF not working as expected

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm relatively new to the terminal programming. I'm trying to run an `IF` condition within a `FOR` loop. (The command is to be run by a cronjob)

`for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; if [ $i>3 ]; then echo $i; fi; done`

I want it to output as

```
1
2
3
4
4
5
5
```

But the real output from that command is

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
```

Could anyone help me point out the mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Oops misread the question, let me edit!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[` brackets are alias for `test` command and there is no `>` sign in the regular test command. Use `[  $i -gt 3 ]`

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; if  [ $i -gt 3 ] ; then echo $i; fi; done
1
2
3
4
4
5
5
```

You could use bash's arithmetic expansion `(())`  as well

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; if  (( $i>3 )) ; then echo $i; fi; done
1
2
3
4
4
5
5
```

You could use `expr` too, but I guarantee 100% that you will keep on forgetting to `\` escape the `<` and `>` sings, as well as redirect output to `/dev/null`:

```
$> if expr 3 \> 2 > /dev/null ; then echo YES; else echo NO ; fi                           
YES
$> if expr 3 \< 2 > /dev/null ; then echo YES; else echo NO ; fi                           
NO
```

Comment: Thank you, It resolves my problem. I can't accept your answer right now since not allowed to accept in a few minutes

Comment: `$1` should be replaced by `$i`, by the way :)

Comment: @aye Thanks for catching that. It's hard to write complete answers on cell phone while running to work. I'm making edits to my answer right now. Will post soon

Comment: `[ $(($i>3)) -eq "1" ]`? O.o Just `if (( i > 3 ))` without anything extra will do. It's the cleanest of the lot.

Comment: (And `[[ 1 > 2 ]]` is string comparison. Try `[[ 123 > 2 ]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Editing your command to this should work:

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; if [[ $i -gt 3 ]]; then echo $i; fi; done
```

As an extra improvement, if this command will only be run in bash, It's worth using `[[` instead of `[`.  It does much the same thing but has some nice [additional functionality](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals).

Comment: That's not what op is asking about. Echo only greater than 3 twice

Comment: Just spotted that!

Comment: Could you read again the question, about the output that i want. Thanks!

Comment: @Arronical There is no `>` for greater than in bash, use `[ $i -gt 3 ]`

Comment: @aye Edited to actually do what you asked! ;)

Comment: @Videonauth I must not answer Ask Ubuntu questions on my lunch break, really not sure where my head is today!

Comment: @Arronical We've all been there , answering questions when our focus isn't the best  :) Still shows good commitment though. Keep up the good work !